# retrieved date data from mysql is not the exact data shown on a label in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to display the contents of a certain column on a `label`, but when i get to this certain column which is in a `date` datatype.. it adds a "12:00:00 AM" and i want to remove it so that only the correct date and time pair will be joined together in a string. i am not allowed to alter the database table..
how can i eliminate that "12:00:00 AM" part of the string.. is it possible?
i am sure that its a `date` data type, but it gives one that looks like a `datetime` datatype.
well i'm clearly a newbie, and any suggestion or help is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

[the part of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpciK.jpg)

[when i retrieve a certain data in the db table, the label is not showing the exact same thing thats on the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzCib.jpg)

```
private void dbdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //db read
        string constring = "SERVER = localhost; user id = root; password =; database = mpdb";
        string Query = "select * from mpdb.cicotbl where cico_no='" + this.textBox1.Text + "';";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string firstdate = myReader.GetString("CINd");
                string seconddate = myReader.GetString("COUTd");
                string time1 = myReader.GetString("CINt");
                string time2 = myReader.GetString("COUTt");
                dbdate1.Text = firstdate + " " + time1;
                dbdate2.Text = seconddate + " " + time2;
            }
            conDataBase.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because the date is stored in the database as a date-time variable, a short fix is to use:

```
DateTime firstdate = DateTime.Parse(myReader.GetString("CINd"));
DateTime seconddate = DateTime.Parse(myReader.GetString("COUTd"));
string firstdatestring = firstdate.ToLongDateString();
string seconddatestring = seconddate.ToLongDateString();
string time1 = myReader.GetString("CINt");
string time2 = myReader.GetString("COUTt");
dbdate1.Text = firstdatestring + " " + time1;
dbdate2.Text = seconddatestring + " " + time2;
```

Comment: i used ToShortDateString();

Comment: im very sorry. im new to stack overflow, i didnt know how to mark an answer as an answer. i thought clicking the upvote was the way of making it accepted as an answer. im really sorry. anyway thanks again